# Build a min max stack using a linkedlist

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack, nodes

**Problem**

The idea is to construct a MIN MAX stack that can do the following operations in constant time.

> 1. Push
> 2. Pop
> 3. Peek
> 4. getMinValue
> 5. getMaxValue

**My Approach**

My idea is that I have created a node structure that will store its own value and the min and max value at the time of insertion.

So for example when I insert value 4 to the stack since the head is null the node will set the min and max as its own value. However if the head is not null at time of insertion then we do a compare of the new nodes value and the heads min and max and if the new nodes value for example is smaller then the min value will be its own value otherwise it will take on the head's min value. The same logic is applied to maintain for both min and max.

So at any given time we can peek at the head and get the min and max value of the stack at that given time.

**CODE**

```
  static class MinMaxStack {
        Node head = null;

        class Node{
            Integer value;
            Node next;
            Integer min;
            Integer max;

            public Node(Integer val){
                this.value = val;
            }
        }

    public Integer peek() {
            return head.value;
        }
    public Integer pop() {
             Node temp = head;
            if(head.next != null){
                head = temp.next;
                temp.next = null;
            }else{
                head = null;
            }
            return temp.value;
    }


    public void push(Integer number) {
            Node x = new Node(number);
            if(head == null){
                head = x;
                x.min = x.value;
                x.max = x.value;
            }else{
                x.min = x.value < head.min ? x.value : head.min;
                x.max = x.value > head.max ? x.max : head.max;
                x.next = head;
                head = x;
            }
    }


    public Integer getMin() {
      return head.min;
    }


    public Integer getMax() {
      return head.max;
    }
    }
```

**ISSUE**

I know there are other ways to implement this but I decided to take the linked-list route. For some reason my code is failing test cases so I am not sure if I did something wrong. I just want to make sure my logic is fine as I am not able to pick up the issue.

Comment: Please also share the test cases which are correct and which are failing.

Comment: Why does each node need to store a min/max? Why wouldn't the list just keep track of the min/max in its own variables?

Comment: @JonnyHenly then that would violate the idea of being able to get min in constant time. if we pop value that use to be the globalMin we need to know the new globalMin and we would have to scan the entire list again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two things that can be fixed:

`push`:

In this line :  `x.max = x.value > head.max ? x.max : head.max;`
you are reassigning `x.max` to `x.max`, change it to:

`x.max = x.value > head.max ? x.value : head.max;`

`pop`:

All you need here is:

```
public Integer pop() throws EmptyStackException {
  if (head == null) throw new EmptyStackException();
  Integer result = head.value;
  head = head.next;
  return result;
}
```

Essentially you are popping the `head`.
Now you may wonder whether that would affect `min`, `max`.

It won't. There are three cases:

1. The current `head` before popping could be the `min` value.
2. The current `head` before popping could be the `max` value.
3. Both 1 and 2.

In all cases, if you remove the `head`, its next node already contains the next best `min`, `max` values, because you are updating them during the push.

Comment: Well spotted, most of it are improvements, the real mistake is the x.max which should be an x.value.

Comment: Makes sense, the x.max was a silly mistake and yeah i think my pop logic was wrong now i am passing all test cases.